# postgres varchar needs casting

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I have 2 tables in 2 different schemas scha schb (e.g) and in scha I have a several tables that are all made of varchar as I had to format some data [it was part of the task]

now I have the same tables but with different types in schb.

The problem is this, Wherever I have a type which involves numbers (money, numerical, date), it's giving me an error to CAST.

Is there a way where I can CAST, without the need of copying one coloumn after another (copying it all in one go)

for example

```
INSERT INTO schb.customer
SELECT "col1", "col2" "col3 **(needs casting)**...."
FROM scha.customer
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not cast the columns in the SELECT clause? Or is "how do I cast values in a SELECT" the real question?

Comment: "HOW" is the question if you do not mind Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [SELECT clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) is not a list of columns, it is a list of expressions (which usually involve columns). A type cast is an expression so you can put them right into your SELECT. PostgreSQL supports [two casting syntaxes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS):

```
CAST ( expression AS type )
expression::type
```

The first is standard SQL, the `::` form is PostgreSQL-specific. If your `schb.customer.col3` is (for example) `numeric(5,2)`, then you'd say:

```
INSERT INTO schb.customer (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, cast(col3 as numeric(5,2))
FROM scha.customer

-- or

INSERT INTO schb.customer (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3::numeric(5,2)
FROM scha.customer
```

Note that I've included the column list in the INSERT as well. You don't have to do that but it is a good idea as you don't have to worry about the column order and it makes it easy to skip columns (or let columns assume their default values with explicitly telling them to).